What is the best place to add the language folder in url from an SEO perspective?
I have a website with multiple languages so we added the language folder after the root domain directly, and then each folder after that is localized to the same language. For example:
XYZ.com/en/blog/electric-cars/
XYZ.com/sv/blogg/elbilar/
Is that better or I should consider moving the language folder after the whole main folders?
Like:
XYZ.com/blog/electric-cars/en/
XYZ.com/blog/electric-cars/sv/
What do you think is better from an SEO perspective?

This answer seems to suggest that your first example is better, because URLs should be translated into the target language as much as possible.

From an SEO perspective, it's generally better to keep the language folder right after the root domain, like in your current setup

Please improve your answer by quoting appropriate references
